# Looping check in Java

Tags: java

Can anyone guide me on how to do a looping compare data using Java?

***Example***: I have a lot of section from `1 to 30`
each time I need to take 2 section to compare are the data is (A, A) or not?

I need to compare `sec1, sec2 if data is (A,A)` then `add 1` to output then continue compare to next section `sec2, sec3 and so on`...

```
sec1    A
sec2    B
sec3    C
sec4    A
sec5    E
sec6    A
sec7    A
.
.
.
.
.
.
```

Comment: what you have tried so far ?

Comment: Don't expect anything but downvotes for such a question. People are here to help with specific problems; but not to solve them for your completely. In other words: show us the code you created so far. And a side note before posting code: most likely you want to read some basic material regarding **arrays**; what they are, and how to use them in Java. Having variables named sec1 to sec30 ... somehow indicates that you are lacking some very basic understanding in this area ...

Comment: Very vague requirements without any effort to show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that `sec1,sec2` are all the string in the array.

```
char [] sections =  {'A','A','B','A','A','B','B','A','A','B'};
int count = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < sections.length - 1; i++)
{
   if(sections[i] == 'A' && sections[i+1] == 'A')//compare with what you want to
   {
     count++;
   }
}
System.out.println(count);
```

**EDIT**

```
try
{
 String query = "select * from emp;*;
 ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

 while(rs.next())
     {
      String []sections = new String[30];
      for(int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
      {
      sections[i] = rs.getString(i+1);
      }
     //now add your checking logic here...
     }
    }
catch(Exception e)
{
 e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Hi Uma, thanks for your guide.. i tested, but I hit error, Hope you can guide me how to get the database value into array?String query = "xxx ";  // here my query will return section (a lot of section here)
try{
while (Result.next() ) {
 String wcA= Result.getString( 1 );
String wcB= Result.getString( 2 );
// I need help on here.. i dont know how to loop in all the section value to compare?
String[] checkList = { /* here are my checking" };
 for ( int j = 0; j < arrTestWC.length; j++ ) {
       if ( wcA.equalsIgnoreCase( checkLIst[j] ) && wcb.equalsIgnoreCase( checkList [j] ) ) {     
}